# Implementing simple markdown directive in vuejs, reactivity problem

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-i18n

I tried to implement a very simple Markdown formatter directive (just bold, emphasize, and strike-trough) to be a bit more independent from `vue-18n` formatting. The current directive looks like this:

```js
    import _Vue from 'vue';
    
    const emphasize = (str: string) => {
      const matched = /(\*|_)(.*?)(\*|_)/gm;
      return str.replace(matched, '<em>$2</em>');
    };
    
    const strong = (str: string) => {
      const matched = /(\*\*|__)(.*?)(\*\*|__)/gm;
      return str.replace(matched, '<strong>$2</strong>');
    };
    
    const strikeThrough = (str: string) => {
      const matched = /~~(.*?)~~/gm;
      return str.replace(matched, '<s>$2</s>');
    };
    
    const fromMd = (str: string) => strikeThrough(emphasize(strong(str)));
    
    export default {
      install: (Vue: typeof _Vue): void => {
        /* eslint-disable no-param-reassign */
        Vue.directive('tmd', {
          bind(el: HTMLElement) {
            el.innerHTML = fromMd(el.innerHTML);
          },
          inserted(el: HTMLElement) {
            el.innerHTML = fromMd(el.innerHTML);
          },
          update(el: HTMLElement) {
            el.innerHTML = fromMd(el.innerHTML);
          },
        });
      },
    };
```

I use it like this:

```html
<p v-tmd >{{ $t('path-to-translation', ) }}</p>
```

So far it works fine, BUT the problem is, that when I change the language, the directive seems not to be updated. It receives the `updated` event, but the `el.innerHTML` is not updated, so it renders the old one. What would be the best practice here to achieve this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why parsing `el.innerHTML` doesn't work, but you can parse the `vnode` text instead:

```js
export default {
  install: Vue => {
    const childrenTextToMd = (el, binding, vnode) => {
      if (vnode.children) {
        el.innerHTML = vnode.children
          .map(child => fromMd(child.text))
          .join('')
      }
    }

    Vue.directive('tmd', {
      inserted: childrenTextToMd,
      update: childrenTextToMd
    })
  }
}
```

***Side note:** `strikeThrough()` has a replacement for `$2`, but there's only one capture group, so it should be `$1`.*

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/reactive-markdown-directive-or5w4?file=/src/tmd-directive.js:511-823)